# How to line up different widgets horizontally in Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm trying to combine a couple different widgets to make controls for a plot where you can select the axes and change input value parameters. I have it organized how I think it should be but it doesn't line up any of the different widgets smoothly.

[Widgets not lined up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ppo6.png)

How do I make that work in a relatively clean manner? My code is below and I'm outputting to notebook. Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show, curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column, row, gridplot, layout, WidgetBox
from bokeh.models.widgets import CheckboxButtonGroup, Slider, RadioGroup, TextInput


inputs = pd.read_csv("surrogate_inputs.csv")
slider_list = []
variables = []
empty = []
textinp_list = []

for i in range(0,len(inputs.Input)):
  slider = Slider(title=None, start=inputs.Min[i], end=inputs.Max[i], value=inputs.Init[i], step=inputs.Step[i])
  textinput = TextInput(title=None, value=str(slider.value))
  slider_list.append(slider)
  variables.append(inputs.Input[i])
  textinp_list.append(textinput)
  empty.append(" ")

sliders = column(slider_list)
textinp = column(textinp_list)
radio_group_x = RadioGroup(labels=empty, active=0)
radio_group_y = RadioGroup(labels=variables, active=1)
input_section = row([radio_group_x, radio_group_y, sliders, textinp], sizing_mode='scale_height')
show(input_section)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 columns in one row (single widgets like the Radiogroups in your exampel automatically get wrapped up in a Widgetbox object which is like a column).
The columns are aligned with each other within a same row, which does not necessarily mean elements in it will be aligned horizontally.

You should try doing 3 rows in one column instead, which might require dropping the radiogroup and have individual radiobuttons:

```
column(row(button1,button1.2,slider1,text1),row(button2,button2.2,slider2,text2),row(button3,button3.2,slider3,text3))
```

or equivalently with gridplot:

```
gridplot([[button1,button1.2,slider1,text1],[button2,button2.2,slider2,text2],[button3,button3.2,slider3,text3]])
```

Comment: Seb, this works somewhat well but the spacing is pretty huge and things aren't still really lined up. I'm looping through the rows I've set up (as I'd like it to be dynamic). I've tried playing with the sizing mode properties but it's not really working. [Here's the updated image](https://imgur.com/a/0H9mq6A).

Comment: Oh a clarification, this refers to the first solution provided.

Comment: @PB it's not "spacing", it's the default size of the row/column elements. You need to either set the width/height of the rows/columns or of the widgets themselves

Comment: Thanks Seb. Sorry about the delay. I think what I'm encountering with the TextInput width is potentially related to [this](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/6427). Tweaking it gives weird behavior in how the widgets display - same with changing the width of the Sliders. [See here](https://imgur.com/a/hSVe8JJ). I'm kinda befuddled at this point.